# Sandwich Coding Standards

Tags: coding-standards

I recently spotted the [code for a `wp-lunch.php` file](http://i.hanni.me/2014/05/24/1181/) intended for a WordPress template, what would this look like if following the proper WordPress coding standards?

[image: wp-lunch.php]

```
<?php if ( current_user_can('has_sandwich') ): ?>

    <?php get_sandwich_header(); ?>

        <?php while( has_filling() ): the_filling(); ?>

            <?php get_sandwich_part( 'thick_layer',
    get_filling() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php get_sandwich_footer(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Excellent question, let the games begin!

Comment: I think the perfect question to ask here, how should `the_filling()` look like

Comment: What do all those WP devs do on weekends? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happen if the user don't have capability to eat sandwich? WSOF?

If I'd want to follow average default themes templates, I'd go for

```
// eat-sandwich.php (as @Rarst said avoid wp-lunch.php as it's not part of WP core)

get_header( 'sandwich' );

if ( current_user_can( 'eat_sandwich' ) ) {

  get_template_part( 'eat-sandwich', 'content' );

} else { // user can't eat sandwich. An apple?

  $alternative = apply_filters( 'alternative_to_sandwich', 'apple' );

  if ( 'sandwich' == $alternative ) {
     // No sandwich allowed!
     $alternative = 'apple';
  }

  get_template_part( "eat-$alternative", 'content' );

}

get_footer( 'sandwich' );
```

And then

```
// eat-sandwich-content.php

$fillings = get_fillings_query(); // in functions.php

if ( $fillings->have_posts() ) : while ( $fillings->have_posts() ) :

   get_template_part( 'filling', get_filling_type() );

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

else :

  _e( 'Sorry, no fillings found. Eating an apple may help to stop hunger.', 'txtdomain');

endif;
```

Comment: This query would break if there was no bread, since bread is not considered a filling and an essential part of a sandwich. I recommend adding `get_ingredients();` instead of `get_fillings_query();` of which bread and filling are a part of. Also the filling should have a front facing JSON API;)

Answer (score 5):

```
<!-- file shouldn't be named wp-lunch.php as it's not part of WP core -->

<?php if ( current_user_can( 'eat_sandwich' ) ): // more specific verb makes more sense to me ?>

    <?php get_header( 'sandwich' ); // native function accepts type argument ?>

    <?php while ( have_fillings() ): the_filling(); // maybe native API, but feels acceptable wrapper for semantics ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'filling', get_filling_type() ); // native API, what would be `thick_layer` base? ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); // reset $post global ?>

    <?php get_footer( 'sandwich' ); // native function accepts type argument ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Spacing adjusted for coding style, etc.

Sandwich template with bit of Twig, eaten on [Meadow](https://github.com/Rarst/meadow) will look something like:

```
{% if ( current_user_can( 'eat_sandwich' ) ) %}

    {% include 'header-sandwich.twig' %}

    {% loop fillings %}

        {% include 'filling-' ~ get_filling_type() ~ '.twig' ignore missing %}

    {% endloop %}

    {% include 'footer-sandwich.twig' %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: All that `<?php` give me chills.

Comment: @G.M. I thought about introducing Mustache template, but who wants mustache in their sandwich?

Comment: If I found a Twig in my sandwich I could handle it, but not a Mustache.

Answer (score 1):

No need for all of the opening and closing delimiters or clear linespaces when already indented:

```
<?php
if ( current_user_can( 'has_sandwich' ) ) {
    get_sandwich_header();
    while ( has_filling() ) {
        the_filling();
        get_sandwich_part( 'thick_layer', get_filling() );
    }
    get_sandwich_footer();
}
```

Should probably have a reset filling data afterwards too...